Parent component not receiving emit from child component
I have a child component <customer-add-form> that I'm using on a parent AddCustomerToClassComponent like this:
<customer-add-form #customerForm>
        (addExistingCustomer)="handleAddExistingCustomer($event)"
        (addNewCustomer)="handleAddNewCustomer($event)"
        (testFunc)="handleTest($event); console.log('Parent template capturing
        event:', $event)" >

I have a few handlers setup to respond to EventEmitters from CustomerAddFormComponent, for instance (testFunc)="handleTest($event)" I've also added the additional console.log inline to see if the subcription triggers at all (it doesn't).
Inside the child component, I have a simple setup:
<button (click)="testEmit()">test</button>
@Output() testFunc = new EventEmitter();`
testEmit(): void {
    console.log('Child emitting testFunc event:', 'test');
    this.testFunc.emit('test');
  }

Inside the parent, I never see the breakpoint hit here:
  handleTest(foo: string): void {
    debugger;
  }

I've experimented with different method signatures for handleTest like handleTest(event: Event): void. None of these work either. There must be something outside the basic @Output / Emit structure that is causing this bug. Here is a PasteBin to the code for both parent/child components/templates: https://pastebin.com/aCgpEhWs

Your customer-add-form markup looks odd, has two closing tags?

console.log() doesn‘t work in the html template file. If you want to check if you comes into the handleTest() method, add there console.log("inside handleRest method").

@mindparse I'm not seeing what you're referring to. I'm not seeing extra closing tags anywhere. Can you be more specific?

I've removed the console.log in the template - same result.

@mindparse You're a genius! I can't believe I didn't see that! The extra closing angle bracket (>) before I define the attributes and subscriptions. Of course! Thanks!

The problem is that console is not known to the template. If you remove the following from the template it should work:
; console.log('Parent template capturing event:', $event)

Alternately, if you add the following to the parent component and leave the template intact, it should also work:
console = console;

It looks strange, but what it does is assign the class property console the global console. This way the template can call console.log, as it does it indirectly through the class property.

I've removed the console.log from the template - same result.

i corrected typos here:
<customer-add-form #customerForm
 (addExistingCustomer)="handleAddExistingCustomer($event)"
 (addNewCustomer)="handleAddNewCustomer($event)"
 (testFunc)="handleTest($event)">

you forgot to Add explicit type here:
@Output() testFunc = new EventEmitter<string>();

it should work now.

I think no, then console.log() doesn‘t work in a template file

I've tried specifying the type of the EventEmitter value ( for the testFunc, as you suggest) and this doesn't work. It should work without explicit typing. As you can see, the two other EventEmitters I have specified the type and this doesn't work.
As a few of you have pointed out, the console.log won't work in the template. This was just a stab at troubleshooting why the Parent wasn't receiving the emit from the Child. I've removed it, and I have the same result.
